# Append value to the empty lists to a list of list by indices of those empty list using python

Tags: python, list, arraylist, python-itertools

I have a nested list like this,

```
 l=[[],[],[1,2],[],[5],[],[4,3],[]]
```

Now I got the indices of the empty lists of the nested list.

```
indices=[0,1,3,5,7]
```

Now, I want to insert/append zero to the empty lists by index, so the list should look like,

```
l=[[0],[0],[1,2],[0],[5],[0],[4,3],[0]]
```

I can do it using,

```
x=[]
for i in l:
    if len(i)==0:
        x.append([0])
    else:
        x.append(i)
```

But the execution time will be huge, I am looking for sort cuts to do it efficiently.

Comment: What are sort cuts?

Comment: I wouldn't expect a huge improvement of the execution time

Comment: I mean I want to reduce execution time. any slight improvement will be appreciated

Comment: `len(i) == 0` is not necessary (and potentially slower), you can use `if not i` to be more pythonic and maybe slightly faster.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension, but this wont guarantee an improvement in the execution time:

```
l = [[], [], [1, 2], [], [5], [], [4, 3], []]

result = [e or [0] for e in l]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[0], [0], [1, 2], [0], [5], [0], [4, 3], [0]]
```

Comment: While this is true, I do not see why this should be substantially faster. In essence the list comprehension iterates over the list l. Edit: I agree, the constant might be different of course.

Comment: @stephanmg I would be surprise there is a data structure, or some sort of algorithm that would improve the time complexity of the algorithm of the OP. Given that presumption, one could only improve on the constants, and in my experience list comprehensions are faster than for loops.

Comment: the list comp will certainly be a bit faster. This answer does not perform any append method either (append usually takes time). You are right that it wouldn't be substantially faster but it definitely will be more than just a bit faster

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarification. So +1 for list comprehension. @Daniel Mesejo: I agree on the constant comment.